# How to force wget to convert all links to relative ones?

Tags: wget

For having an offline version of Oracles Java tutorials¹, where all links to the Java API shall point to the also downloaded local version of the Java API docs, I use the following wget command (look out if trying: gets over 25,000 files):

```
wget -mkp -nH -nv -E  --accept-regex ".*javase/8/docs/api.*|.*javase/tutorial.*" http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/
```

Unfortunately only a part of the links are converted to point correctly to the local files. All files under `javase/tutorial` are fine, all files under `javase/8/docs/api` do not point to the local files, but instead point still to the online version.

Any ideas what's wrong?

––––

¹ I know there is a downloadable version of the tutorials, but it's API links point only to the online Java API doc.

Comment: See [*man wget*](https://linux.die.net/man/1/wget).

Comment: The man page looks very nice. And now?